# How to compare two rfs directories with `diff`?

Tags: linux, filesystems, diff

I've two RFS (`RFS` = `Root File System`) directories, which I would like to compare to each other with `diff`. Both directories represent an RFS of some other system, and they may contain links. If those links are absolute, they will point to something useless.

For example, I've one RFS with the following symlink (inside the RFS):

```
/usr/test -> /home/test/file1
```

Now I've this complete RFS inside a directory named `/home/user/compare`, and the absolute paths of both files mentioned above are

```
/home/user/compare/usr/test
/home/user/compare/home/test/file1
```

Clearly, the symlink `/home/user/compare/usr/test` doesn't point to the right file. And because of that a comparison with the files in `/home/usr/compare` with some other RFS directory will fail for those symlinks.

Is it possible to setup `diff` so it assumes not `/` as root but `/home/user/compare` as root (for the comparison), so that the given absolute symlink points to something valid, and `diff` takes it into account?

Maybe there is a similar Linux command I can use for that?

Comment: what do you mean by `rfs`?

Comment: in any case, the symlinks are not evaluated by `diff`, but instead by the kernel, so no, `diff` should not be able to do as you requested.

Comment: rfs = root file system. This is being used when working to create/change/... a complete root filesystem, which is being used within a different system. You might have one in `/home/user/subsystem` which contain directories like `usr`, `bin`, `home`, `etc`, `var`, `lib`...